# Alterando taxonomia padrão do wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Atualmente as paginas de categorias do meu site possuí a seguinte taxonomia   www.site.com/category/programa01;  Não consigo alterar essa taxonomia para programa/programa01. Existe alguma forma de fazer essa alteração ?

Comment: Tentou através dos permalinks?

Comment: Sim mas é somente possível alterar o slug da postagem mas não da página especifica da categoria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Você deve mudar a **label** da categoria, veja o exemplo:

```
<?php 

function change_category_taxonomy_label() {
        global $wp_taxonomies;

    $labels = $wp_taxonomies['category']->labels;

    if(!empty($labels)){
        $search = array('Categories', 'Category', 'category');
        $replace = array('Programa01', 'Programa01', 'programa01');

        foreach ($labels as $key => $label) {
            $label = str_replace($search, $replace, $label);
            $wp_taxonomies['category']->labels->$key = $label;
        }
    }
    $wp_taxonomies['category']->label = 'Programa01';

 }

 function jwh_manage_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['categories'] = 'Programa01';
       return $columns;
}

function jwh_column_init() {
  add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns' , 'jwh_manage_columns' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init' , 'jwh_column_init' );
```

2) Ou você pode criar uma taxonomia personalizada. Basta verificar o manual:

```
https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies
```

Comment: Onde devo adicionar essa função ? tentei colocar no meu functons do tema mas sem sem sucesso

Comment: Este código é apenas um exemplo, eu não testei ele no meu Wordpress. Sim, ele deve ser utilizado no arquivo de funções do seu template.

Comment: Eu implantei no functions do tema mas não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

[image: local para alterar a taxonomia das categorias e tags]Depois de acessar o painel administrativo do WordPress, vá em em configurações, depois Links Permanentes e em Opcional altere a base das categorias. Dá para fazer isso até com as tags!